# Custom Dictionary not working with Code Analysis

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-analysis, naming

I have a class in my sourcecode:

```
public class TypeUserdef : SymbolType
```

which is a DTO for XML Serialization, now the code analysis reports a warning:

```
MSBUILD : warning CA1704: Microsoft.Naming : Correct the spelling of 'Userdef' 
in type name 'TypeUserdef'.
```

I put the entry into the user dictionary (a customer dictionary in my project set to buildAction = "CodeAnalysisDictionary"):

```
<Dictionary>
  <Words>
    <Recognized>
      <word>userdef</word>
    </Recognized>
  </Words>
</Dictionary>
```

Now the funny thing is the dictionary works very well for a lot terms. Just the term "userdef" and "vars" report errors. (Even spelling errors in the same code file can be ignored). What is so special about those terms above?

Comment: did you remove it from `<unrecognized>`? Several posts mention that  if a term is in both, `<unrecognized>` takes priority.

Comment: i don't have a unrecognized tag at all. Is there any system dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not sure exactly where it is on VS2013. Preferred method is probably to apply a CustomDictionary.xml to your project in Solution Explorer and leave the root dictionary as is.

Comment: i found one, but it does not contain "userdef"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the Problem, while i know that xml is case sensitive it is quite difficult to spot that some entries in a few hundred lines of xml are lower cased...

```
<Word></Word> works as expected.
```